# angular 4 how to slice only for groped?

Tags: angular

HTML

```
<h4>NgFor (grouped)</h4>
 <ul *ngFor="let group of peopleByCountry | slice:0:1 "> 
   <li>{{ group.country }}</li>
   <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let person of group.people" | slice:0:1 > 
      {{ person.name }}
    </li>
   </ul>
 </ul>
```

TS file

```
peopleByCountry: any[] = [
    {
      'country': 'UK',
      'people': [
        {
          "name": "Douglas  Pace"
        },
        {
          "name": "Mcleod  Mueller"
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      'country': 'US',
      'people': [
        {
          "name": "Day  Meyers"
        },
        {
          "name": "Aguirre  Ellis"
        },
        {
          "name": "Cook  Tyson"
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
```

I want to show first people only for each country.

but when i slice its only hide person can we solve this?

i want this in only in one array but need to show only limited content from each group.

Comment: Not sure I understand, what does not work right now?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to iterate trough people if you want to show only the first person.

```
<h4>NgFor (grouped)</h4>
 <ul *ngFor="let group of peopleByCountry"> 
   <li>{{ group.country }}</li>
   <ul>
    <li > 
      {{ group.people[0].Name }}
    </li>
   </ul>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

To enhance the answer already given you can add an if-clause to check if the people array has content otherwise it may give an error.

```
<h4>NgFor (grouped)</h4>
<ul *ngFor="let group of peopleByCountry "> 
    <li>{{ group.country }}</li>
    <ul>
        <li *ngIf="group.people.length > 0"> 
            {{ group.people[0].name }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</ul>`
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uq3cyk5d/

**Edit**

After I saw your comment I think your selection of names to be shown looks quite random. To let you decide which names should be shown I just introduced an other attribute to your data. With the show property you can than define which names should be shown in the list and which not.

data:

```
peopleByCountry: any[] = [
{
  'country': 'UK',
  'people': [
    {
      "name": "Douglas  Pace",
      "show": true
    },
    {
      "name": "Mcleod  Mueller",
      "show": false
    },
  ]
},
{
  'country': 'US',
  'people': [
    {
      "name": "Day  Meyers",
      "show": true
    },
    {
      "name": "Aguirre  Ellis",
      "show": true
    },
    {
      "name": "Cook  Tyson",
      "show": false
    }
  ]
}
```

];

html:

```
<ul *ngFor="let group of peopleByCountry "> 
    <li>{{ group.country }}</li>
    <ul>
        <div *ngFor="let person of group.people">
            <li *ngIf="person.show"> 
                {{person.name}}
            </li>
        </div>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

I updated the fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/uq3cyk5d/2

Comment: Hi,

I want to show first "name": "Douglas  Pace" in first list and second list "name": "Day  Meyers" & "name": "Aguirre  Ellis"